# Invoke ADF pipeline from powershell specifying branch?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-powershell

Is it possible to use Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline and somehow specify a branch for pipeline to use? Currently our powershell test harness is only able to target 'live mode' ADF.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline to run a debug pipeline for a specific branch. I believe the only way to execute a debug run for a pipeline is directly in the ADF UI. The only way you can run a pipeline using REST or Powershell is through the actual physical ADF that you publish to.

I'm curious as to the use case for this though? Why would you systematically need to have debug runs? Usually people develop a pipeline, debug it and make sure it's good, then publish it so that it can be triggered or called.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that Trent. The idea was to be able to target automated tests (or the development of automated tests) at ADF development branch work, prior to the work being published.

Comment: Like run a debug on every commit to the feature branch (save in ADF)? Interesting, but probably not very cost effective as you are charged on a per activity basis even in debug runs.